# Sequential execution of 2 functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, order-of-execution

I am not very familiar with async/await and promises. Currently having two individual functions - to export files from X and upload those files to Y correspondingly.

```
export const exportFiles = async (A: string, B: string) : Promise<void> => {
    // statements to do the export
    return;
};


export const uploadFiles = async (C: string, D: string) : Promise<void> => {
    // statements to do the upload
    return;
};
```

When I try to make the function calls like:

```
exportFiles(A, B)
uploadFiles(C, D)
```

`uploadFiles` gets executed first since `exportFiles` is a time consuming function.

How do I program the order of execution? I want `uploadFiles` to start execution only after `exportFiles` gets executed fully.

Comment: Use `await` - that's what it's for - to instruct JS to wait for an async function to finish before processing the rest of the code.

Comment: "*`uploadFiles` gets executed first*" - no, it's called second, after `exportFiles`. It might *finish* first though, while `exportFiles` is still running its background tasks.

Comment: "*I am not very familiar with async/await and promises.*" - they're the right choice though for solving this! I recommend you get familiar with them.

Comment: @Bergi How do I get the second function to start executing after the first function has completed execution?

Comment: @VLAZ I tried to call the functions like 'await exportFiles(A,B)' followed by 'await uploadFiles(C,D)' but still get the same output.

Comment: @AMDN If you get the same output even with `await`, then your async functions are not actually well defined. Without knowing the code in the function, it's not possible to figure out exactly what's wrong with them.